# Virtualbox DNS concerns

Tags: virtualbox, dns

Help, I can't join a client pc to server's domain if default gateway of the client is not set to as the server's IP address. Problem setting the server's ip address as the gateway of client is that you will have no internet connection even setting up IP for DNS server of the client.

Questions:

1. How can I set the gateway of client same to the server and also allow me to join this client computer to the server's domain?
2. Why if i ping using client's pc with DNS server setup to same as the DNS server of the server, it was not being resolved after not being resolved from the gateway?

   - Server IP - 10.0.2.15
   - Default Gateway of Server - 10.0.2.1
   - Client PC - 10.0.2.6

Comment: I think you’re confusing things. Joining Active Directory requires the DNS server point at an AD DNS server. That’s all. The default gateway etc are derived from the network topology.

Comment: wow thank you, it works.. you were right i was confusing it.. thank you!